# How to create an auto-incrementing id with a fixed length (sequelize)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

So I am trying to use sequelize auto-increment on ids. However, I need the number to have a fixed length of 8 numbers.

**for example:** the sequence would look like `00000001`, `00000002`, `00000003`, ...

How do we do that?

I am using **sequelize** with **postgres**

Comment: Use a simple integer and format the number when you **display** it.

Comment: hm, I need them to be saved as such @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2):

I also faced almost this kind of situation. I did it like below.

```
CREATE TABLE cpl(
  id serial,
  incre character varying default concat(substring('00000000',1,8 - length(currval('cpl_id_seq')::text)),currval('cpl_id_seq')),
  name text
);
```

`INSERT INTO cpl(name) VALUES('cris'),('leo');`

**Result**

```
id     |    incre           |   name    |       
-----------------------------------------
1      |   00000001         |  cris     |
2      |   00000002         |  leo      |
```

Comment: With Postgres 11, you could make that a generated column: `incre text generated always as (lpad(id::text, 8, '0')) stored,`

Comment: I tried the way you offered but there is something wrong. Here is the link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4fcdfe8553b53a183dc4c1a17cbbe95a

Comment: Ah, sorry my fault. They were introduced in 12: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e500de52925267fe950d72d996afef17

Comment: Yes this is more convenient way. I did not know.

Comment: is it possible to use that auto-increment in a sequelize model? if so how please? @a_horse_with_no_name